# Gauß sum and primitive character

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, gauss-sums

I am working with Daniel Marcus "Number Field" Book. And I have a question to the following Lemma:
$$\tau_k(\chi)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \bar\chi(k)\tau(\chi), & \textrm{if }(k,m)=1 \\
         0, & \textrm{if }(k,m)>1\end{array}\right.$$
With $\chi$ a primitive character modulo $m$. For the proof of the case $(k,m)=1$ he writes:
as $a$ runs through $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$, so does $ak$ if $(k,m)=1$.
I understand this argument, but not why $\tau_k(\chi)=\bar\chi(k)\tau(\chi)$ follows.

If I consider $\tau_k(\chi) = \sum\limits_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}\chi(a)e^{2\pi iak/m}$. Then By the argument above I can say:
$\sum\limits_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}\chi(a)e^{2\pi iak/m} = \sum\limits_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}\chi(ak)e^{2\pi iak/m} = \chi(k)\sum\limits_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}\chi(a)e^{2\pi iak/m} = \chi(k)\tau_k(\chi)$.

How does he get $\bar\chi(k)$ instead of $\chi(k)$. And what exactly is $\bar\chi(k)$?

Comment: You should give the **exact** reference in the nice book by Marcus: page, exercise, lemma...

Comment: sorry, it's in my version, the 'thirs corrected printing 1995' on page 198 in chapter 7

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that $\;\overline{\chi}(k)=\chi(k)^{-1}\;$ , as $\;|\chi(k)|=1\;$

Comment: ok.. but how do I come from $\tau_k(\chi)$ to $\chi^{-1}(k)\tau_k(\chi)$? I only see that I get $\tau_k(\chi)= \sum\limits_a \chi(a)\chi(k)e^{2\pi i ak/m}$. and then this is $\chi(k)\tau(\chi)$ no? Or what do I have wrong here?

Comment: It's a pity that such a nice book like Marcus' hasn't yet, apparently, been re-printed in a decent way and all the copies I know still use that horrible, terrible and disgusting printing used in cheap, non-important books from the 1960's and 1970's....a pity.

Comment: I'm not sure that Marcus calls $\;\tau\;$ to...can you tell me so that I won't have to search in the book?

Comment: Ok, I already know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\;\chi(k)^{-1}\chi(k)=\overline{\chi}(k)\chi(k)=|\chi(k)|^2=1\;$ , so

$${}$$

$$\tau_k(\chi)=\sum_{a\in\Bbb Z_m^*}\chi(a)e^{2\pi iak/m}=\sum_{a\in\Bbb Z_m^*}\chi(k)^{-1}\chi(ak)e^{2\pi iak/m}=$$

$${}$$

$$=\overline{\chi}(k)\sum_{ak=:b\in\Bbb Z_m^*}\chi(b)e^{2\pi ib/m}=\overline{\chi}(k)\tau$$

Ah, I still remember this stuff!

Comment: thank you!!!  a lot! Now I see it.
And sorry that I didn't reply to your comment yet.

Comment: NEver mind, @Luca: it is defined just after that lemma.